# Rails and Amazon SimpleDB authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, restful-authentication, amazon-simpledb

I'm trying to use Amazon's SimpleDB with RoR. I need a standard user registration / authentication / roles checking.

Pretty simple, but it seems that restful-authentication plugin did't work with SimpleDB.

Can someone please point me to working solution or should I write my own from scratch?

Anyone? Please?

Answer (score 2):

We (Appoxy) *very* actively maintain SimpleRecord, which is a Ruby library for SimpleDB that is just like ActiveRecord. Very easy to use.

http://gemcutter.org/gems/simple_record

Comment: Have you tested it specifically with devise or are you saying that it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Ruby on Rails SimpleDB article](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1242&categoryID=152) from 2008. It references the rubyforge [aws-sdb](http://rubyforge.org/projects/aws-sdb/) project.

There is also a project on rubyforge called [SimplerDB](http://simplerdb.rubyforge.org/) but it is more of a replacement than a plugin.

Neither of these appear to have been updated recently. If they are not useful to you in their current state, maybe you can contact the authors directly. It may be easier to update one of these projects than to write one from scratch.